# Do topological theorems hold in an arbitrary metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

This [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTXfG.png) from this Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)) suggests that metric spaces can be thought of loosely as a subset of topological spaces. 
Hence, are there any theorems or results that hold for arbitrary topological spaces but do not hold in arbitrary metric spaces?

Comment: I suggest you look up the definition of Topological Space.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I'm well aware of the definition of a topological space, but being closed under unions and finite intersections doesn't really answer the question does it?

Comment: There are many results about some types of top'l spaces that are not metrizable, and some deep theorems on necessary & sufficient conditions for a top'll space to be metrizable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet that's the converse of the question asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, since every metric space is a topological space. That's like asking if there are theorems about polygons which are not valid for triangles.

Answer (score 2):

A metric space is a topological space, hence all theorems or results that hold for arbitrary topological spaces  hold in arbitrary metric spaces.